# Unable to generate wpp trace in a simple driver

Tags: c++, windows, kernel, driver, windows-wpp

I try to display wpp logs from a very simple driver. I followed this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/adding-wpp-software-tracing-to-a-windows-driver).

Below code of my simple driver:

```
#include <ntddk.h>
#include <wdf.h>

#include "trace.h"
#include "driver.tmh"

DRIVER_INITIALIZE DriverEntry;

EVT_WDF_DRIVER_DEVICE_ADD PouetEvtDeviceAdd;

NTSTATUS
DriverEntry(
    _In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT     DriverObject,
    _In_ PUNICODE_STRING    RegistryPath
)
{
    // NTSTATUS variable to record success or failure
    NTSTATUS status = STATUS_SUCCESS;

    // Initialize WPP tracing in DriverEntry
    WPP_INIT_TRACING(DriverObject, RegistryPath);

    // Allocate the driver configuration object
    WDF_DRIVER_CONFIG config;

    // Print "Hello World" for DriverEntry
    KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "KmdfHelloWorld: DriverEntry1\n"));
    DoTraceMessage(TRACE_DRIVER, "DoTraceMessage\n");
    KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "KmdfHelloWorld: DriverEntry2\n"));

    // Initialize the driver configuration object to register the
    // entry point for the EvtDeviceAdd callback, KmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd
    WDF_DRIVER_CONFIG_INIT(&config, PouetEvtDeviceAdd);

    // Finally, create the driver object
    status = WdfDriverCreate(DriverObject, RegistryPath, WDF_NO_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES, &config, WDF_NO_HANDLE );
    return status;
}

NTSTATUS
PouetEvtDeviceAdd(
    _In_    WDFDRIVER       Driver,
    _Inout_ PWDFDEVICE_INIT DeviceInit
)
{
    // We're not using the driver object,
    // so we need to mark it as unreferenced
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Driver);

    NTSTATUS status;

    // Allocate the device object
    WDFDEVICE hDevice;

    // Print "Hello World"
    KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "KmdfHelloWorld: PouetEvtDeviceAdd\n"));
    DoTraceMessage(TRACE_DRIVER, "DoTraceMessage2\n");
    KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "KmdfHelloWorld: PouetEvtDeviceAdd 2\n"));

    // Create the device object
    status = WdfDeviceCreate(&DeviceInit, WDF_NO_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES, &hDevice);
    return status;
}
```

Below code of my wpp header trace.h:

```
#define WPP_CONTROL_GUIDS                                              \
    WPP_DEFINE_CONTROL_GUID(                                           \
        myDriverTraceGuid, (c81e24ca,9d1b,4725,89fd,1abb15c1accc), \
        WPP_DEFINE_BIT(MYDRIVER_ALL_INFO)        /* bit  0 = 0x00000001 */ \
        WPP_DEFINE_BIT(TRACE_DRIVER)             /* bit  1 = 0x00000002 */ \
        )
```

To compile I use Visual Studio Community 2019.

If I use a remote kernel debugger (windbg for exemple), I see the traces made by kdPrintEx functions.
If I open a trace session like below:

```
logman create trace "PouetTraceSession" -p {c81e24ca-9d1b-4725-89fd-1abb15c1accc} 0xffffffff 0xff -o d:\trace\TracePouet.etl
logman start PouetTraceSession
logman stop PouetTraceSession.
```

I check the generated etl file with traceview but there is no trace/event recorded.

Can you tell what I forget ?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: You're using the wrong guid with logman. Needs to be the guid you defined for your driver.

Comment: @Luke, thanks for the remark, it was an error when I wrote the question. I corrected the message.

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me. Not sure what the issue might be.

Comment: @Luke Do you mean, with my code you generate wpp event in the etl file ? Do you see with traceview recorded traces in the generated etl ?

Comment: Using a minimal driver I wrote along with logman commands. Maybe something is off with your project file? I don't know how well Community Edition supports driver projects.

Comment: Hello @Luke, thanks a lot for your answers. Sorry to demand you another things, but I don't know how debug my issue. If I post my vcxproj file could you test it ?

Comment: I could give it a try.

Comment: Thanks. I post the vxproj

Answer (score 0):

The vxproj I used to compile the driver.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|ARM">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>ARM</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|ARM">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>ARM</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|ARM64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>ARM64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|ARM64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>ARM64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{B6D64CFA-34E4-444A-9EEE-BC5D869A8444}</ProjectGuid>
    <TemplateGuid>{1bc93793-694f-48fe-9372-81e2b05556fd}</TemplateGuid>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <MinimumVisualStudioVersion>12.0</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
    <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition="'$(Platform)' == ''">Win32</Platform>
    <RootNamespace>PouetDriver</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <TargetVersion>Windows10</TargetVersion>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0</PlatformToolset>
    <ConfigurationType>Driver</ConfigurationType>
    <DriverType>KMDF</DriverType>
    <DriverTargetPlatform>Universal</DriverTargetPlatform>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <TargetVersion>Windows10</TargetVersion>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0</PlatformToolset>
    <ConfigurationType>Driver</ConfigurationType>
    <DriverType>KMDF</DriverType>
    <DriverTargetPlatform>Universal</DriverTargetPlatform>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <TargetVersion>Windows10</TargetVersion>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0</PlatformToolset>
    <ConfigurationType>Driver</ConfigurationType>
    <DriverType>KMDF</DriverType>
    <DriverTargetPlatform>Universal</DriverTargetPlatform>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <TargetVersion>Windows10</TargetVersion>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0</PlatformToolset>
    <ConfigurationType>Driver</ConfigurationType>
    <DriverType>KMDF</DriverType>
    <DriverTargetPlatform>Universal</DriverTargetPlatform>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|ARM'" Label="Configuration">
    <TargetVersion>Windows10</TargetVersion>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0</PlatformToolset>
    <ConfigurationType>Driver</ConfigurationType>
    <DriverType>KMDF</DriverType>
    <DriverTargetPlatform>Universal</DriverTargetPlatform>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|ARM'" Label="Configuration">
    <TargetVersion>Windows10</TargetVersion>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0</PlatformToolset>
    <ConfigurationType>Driver</ConfigurationType>
    <DriverType>KMDF</DriverType>
    <DriverTargetPlatform>Universal</DriverTargetPlatform>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|ARM64'" Label="Configuration">
    <TargetVersion>Windows10</TargetVersion>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0</PlatformToolset>
    <ConfigurationType>Driver</ConfigurationType>
    <DriverType>KMDF</DriverType>
    <DriverTargetPlatform>Universal</DriverTargetPlatform>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|ARM64'" Label="Configuration">
    <TargetVersion>Windows10</TargetVersion>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0</PlatformToolset>
    <ConfigurationType>Driver</ConfigurationType>
    <DriverType>KMDF</DriverType>
    <DriverTargetPlatform>Universal</DriverTargetPlatform>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <DebuggerFlavor>DbgengKernelDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <DebuggerFlavor>DbgengKernelDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <DebuggerFlavor>DbgengKernelDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <DebuggerFlavor>DbgengKernelDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|ARM'">
    <DebuggerFlavor>DbgengKernelDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|ARM'">
    <DebuggerFlavor>DbgengKernelDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|ARM64'">
    <DebuggerFlavor>DbgengKernelDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|ARM64'">
    <DebuggerFlavor>DbgengKernelDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WppEnabled>true</WppEnabled>
      <WppScanConfigurationData>trace.h</WppScanConfigurationData>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Inf Include="PouetDriver.inf" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FilesToPackage Include="$(TargetPath)" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="Driver.c" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="trace.h" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: The Wpp settings are only present in Debug x64 configuration, and the WppScanConfigurationData setting is not needed. The Debug x64 configuration as is works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Luke, you're right I use only Debug x64 configuration. I just wanted to know how to use the WPP tracing but it's not conclusive. Perhaps it my visual studio version or my system where the driver is installed...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).